# Creating a grid which only exists within a shape

Tags: javascript, canvas

am having trouble doing something in Canvas - I want to create a grid that only exists within that shape. I am able to create the gird to fit the shape if it is a square but if the shape is an unusual shape I do not know how to create the grid.

Here is what I have so far: I only want the grid to exist within the shape

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(75, 50);
ctx.lineTo(40, 65);
ctx.lineTo(100, 105);

ctx.lineTo(200, 15);
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fill();


function drawGrid(context) {
  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out   ';

  for (var x = 40.5; x < 300; x += 10) {
    context.moveTo(x, 0);
    context.lineTo(x, 300);
  }

  for (var y = 0.5; y < 501; y += 10) {
    context.moveTo(0, y);
    context.lineTo(300, y);
  }

  context.strokeStyle = "#ddd";
  context.stroke();
}

drawGrid(ctx)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fom9gtb6/

Answer (score 1):

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out   ';
```

should be

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';`

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation)

> The new shape is only drawn where it overlaps the existing canvas content.

This way the `strokeStyle` is actually used for the grid instead of erasing parts of the shape, which `destination-out` will do.

Comment: How would you go about clipping the hidden squares as I do not want them part of the canvas?

Comment: if you mean you don't want to "render" the grid where no shape is, you should start drawing the vertical lines on the lowest x-coordinate of the shape and the horizontal lines on the lowest y-coordinate of the shape, and set the upper limit to the highest x/y-coordinates. Then the grid will only be drawn (although only rendered in the shape) in the rectangle around the shape